# Can accounts be automatically deployed to Windows Phone 8?

Tags: 8.1, email

Similar to iOS' configuration profiles where you can use an XML file to configure some accounts (like email), can you automatically set up email accounts in Windows Phone through an XML config file or similar?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone does offer the facility where you can add ur email accounts through Settings->emai+accounts->add an account
As soon as you add an account the default settings and your shared preferences gets added automatically to your account.